# Leak on a NSString that's released

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

I'm finishing my app and it's time to fix all the leaks, so I use Instruments.

Here's the code and the leak...

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [connection release];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [responseData release];
    //NSString *responseString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%@%s", "[", responseString, "]"]; 
    // Pour ajouter les [] si y'en a pas autour de tout le contenu JSON, et on doit utiliser responseString2 au lieu de responseString à la ligne ci-dessous
    NSArray *tableau = [responseString JSONValue];
    [responseString release];
    NSDictionary *dico = [tableau objectAtIndex:0];
```

It is `responseString` that leaks BUT I release it after put this value in the array... How can I delete the leak? I don't understand my mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Leaks is showing you where the leak was allocated, not where it was actually leaked;  not the extra `retain` that is causing the problem.

Use the Allocations instrument to track all the retain/release calls on the object and find the extra retain.  That'll be your leak.

---

My explanation of how to do [Heapshot based analysis](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) should help you (as it can be used to track down problems exactly like this, too).

Comment: ok. Can I have an explication how it's run, it make 30 minutes that I try to use it but... x(

Thanks for your ask ;-)